# Creating and editing CSS in Flex3 Air

Tags: css, actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, flex3

I need to create a CSS file via the Flex 3 Air application. I need to create and edit the CSS file and access individual styles by class name. Please give any examples or related links of which you aware.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use Flex that much, but it seems you need to load the CSS file via URLLoader/HTTPService/etc and write a class to parse.

You can probably start from the one that comes with the framework, or have look online and adapt one for your needs. The first this that I found was [this](http://code.google.com/p/flash-camouflage/wiki/CamoStyleSheet). Obviously there could be better alternatives.